# The relationship between __proto__ of an instance and the prototype of its constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

i wrote the code to figure out the relationship between __proto__ of an instance and the prototype of its constructor in javascript for me:

```
// Constructor
var Guy = function( name ) {
       this.name = name;
};

// Prototype
var chinese = {
        region: "china",
        myNameIs: function() {
            return this.name;
        }
};

Guy.prototype = chinese;

var he = new Guy( "Wang" );
var me = new Guy( "Do" );
```

i was given a `false` as i tested whether me.__proto__ is equal to chinese:

```
console.log( "__proto__ of me is chinese? " + chinese == me.__proto__ ); // logs false
```

Why were they not the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `+` has higher precedence than `==`, so you're really doing...

```
( "__proto__ of me is chinese? " + chinese ) == me.__proto__
```

what you need to do is...

```
"__proto__ of me is chinese? " + ( chinese == me.__proto__ )
```

or use a `,` in the `console` call to pass separate arguments...

```
"__proto__ of me is chinese? ", chinese == me.__proto__
```